# How to write mockIto test case for interface object creation and declaration

Tags: mockito

I'm having a method as given below:

```
@Transactional
    public List<EmployeeBean> getEmployeeList(HashMap<String, String> searchCriteria) {
        return employeeDAO.findAll(new Specification<EmployeeBean>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<EmployeeBean> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteria, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
                List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
                predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get("company"), userAuthenticationService.getCurrentUserDetails().getCompanyBean()));
                Set<Entry<String, String>> searchEntrySet = searchCriteria.entrySet();
                for (Entry<String, String> entry : searchEntrySet) {
                    String value = entry.getValue();
                    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(value)) {
                        predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get(entry.getKey()), value));
                    }
                }
                return builder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));
            } 
        });
    }
```

Now I want to mockIto write test case for this method and I want to verify return values of overwritten toPredicate method. How to do this? Please help.

Comment: Why do you want to use Mockito for this?  I'm not sure that it's the right tool for the job.

Comment: I'm going to mock employeeDAO. So I'll write junit to verify data passed to findAll method?

Comment: You could do that.  You'd then want to capture the argument passed to the `findAll` method (read up on what an `ArgumentCaptor` does) and test its `toPredicate` method.

Comment: That means I should capture the argument which will give me object of Specification and using that argument object I should invoke toPredicate method and verify? I think this will solve my problem. Thanks a lot.